# Why use Express Session when already using Redis?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, redis

I have a ticket which says to use Express Session with Redis underneath, as it's memory, but am not sure what the advantage of this approach is. I asked my team, and they tried explaining it, and gave some good points, but I think we just didn't understand each other.

I see the advantages of Redis over server memory (persistence, more secure, less resources). My question is, why do we need session with this approach? We could just use an endpoint to get and set the Redis memory as far as I see. Redis also has a TTL option, so can't see a real advantage of Session here, but since they have WAY more experience, there must be one.

What am I missing?

Comment: One reason is that you don't want your application to depend on every single deployment detail, otherwise when that changes you have to modify the application to support a new technology. Session abstracts away that, so tomorrow you can drop Redis and use a DB or something else and you only have to change a few properties, no application development required

Comment: Ah. Ok yes, that makes a lot more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by GACy20

Redis is necessary with multiple clusters. It's like a really fast db shared by said clusters/instances. One instance of Express can only use one session, therefore it's hard to scale it. See the comment for more details.